# ng-grid hide a certain row on remove row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to find ways to identify rows in ng-grid whether they are modified or deleted or created.

On removal of a row in ng-grid, instead of removing the row i need to hide the row and set a flag saying it is a deleted row.

Can anyone help me on how to hide a row on click of icon/button in ng-grid (on removal).

```
$scope.reasonsGrid = { 
         data: 'myReasons',                    
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'remove', displayName:'', cellTemplate: removeTemplate,enableCellEdit: false,width:30},
          {field: 'code', displayName: 'Reasons',cellTemplate: dropdownTemplate,enableCellEdit: false}]
        };

var removeTemplate ='span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ng-click="removeItem(row.rowIndex)"/>';
 $scope.removeItem = function(index) { //hide a row };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to modify the data item behind the row and set the flag. Your data can then be read from a function that returns a filtered view of these items.

Pass in the row object to your function

```
var removeTemplate ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" ng-click="removeItem(row)"/>';
```

In your function:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(row) {
  var dataItem = row.entity;
  //Do something to dataItem to mark it as deleted
}
```